# Qual é a melhor tradução para "Boilerplate"?

Tags: estrangeirismos

Só encontro textos com o termo "boilerplate" em inglês mas acredito que possa existir o termo em lingua portuguesa.

Comment: Pablo, bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE. Para facilitar a obtenção de respostas, sugiro adicionares uma breve explicação e casos de uso do termo _boilerplate_, para que aqueles que desconhecem o termo possam ajudar.

Comment: Não me lembro de nenhum substantivo com sentido equivalente. Provavelmente acaba traduzido com alguma expressão como "texto padrão", e vai perder um pouco da ideia original.

Comment: Boilerplate1) se usa no contexto jurídico. Agora aqui virou site de tradução?? Texto padrão 2) E em engenharia: chapa de caldeira. Estes são os dois contextos da palavra em inglês.

Comment: Em programação existe o termo [boilerplate code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code), mas não sei se há tradução para o Português. De qualquer forma, sem o contexto adequado, não temos como responder satisfatoriamente, pois não sabemos a quais desses casos a pergunta se refere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Boilerplate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boilerplate)* em Inglês no seu significado original refer-se às chapas de aço em rolo utilizadas na fabricação de caldeiras de aquecimento de água.

Pela sua semelhança em termos de aparência com as chapas curvas utilizadas na imprensa de peças escritas e pelo facto de serem também pré-fabricadas antes de serem utilizadas na linha de montagem final; o termo começou a ser utilizado para se referir aos moldes pré-fabricados de anúncios, colunas, ou textos genéricos a ser reutilizados múltiplas vezes, que eram também fabricados externamente em massa. Ver https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_(text)

A expressão *boilerplate* passou então por extensão a ser utilizada para referir a todo e qualquer excerto de texto genérico que possa ser utilizado como modelo repetidamente sem grandes alterações, por exemplo no contexto legal, em decretos de lei, ou até em código informático. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boilerplate

Por analogia ganhou por vezes metaforicamente o significado de algo genérico, de "fraca qualidade", ou "falta de originalidade", indistinto dos demais por ser feito por repetição, ou industrialmente, por oposição a uma criação original.

Não conheço nenhuma expressão equivalente na língua portuguesa, não sendo uma tradução à letra, eu diria que pode ser vagamente traduzido pela expressão por vezes utilizada em Portugual "*Chapa 3*", quando se quer referir a algo "sempre igual", "feito a eito" ou sem grande atenção ou cuidado.

Comment: O que você disse sobre fraca qualidade não é verdade. Acho que você deveria evitar o urban dictionary porque qualquer pessoa pode escrever qualquer bobagem lá. E não tem nada ver como sempre igual ou feito a eito. Só os tres primeiros parágrafos estão corretos.

Comment: Pois é verdade Urban Dictionary não é boa referência link removido. Não consegui encontrar nenhuma referência mais fidedigna infelizmente, mas tenho visto o termo utilizado com alguma frequência especialmente em blogs de tecnologia e artigos sobre informática.